# Google Analytics CID in Cookie POST request

Tags: google-analytics, get, analytics

I'm currently working on cookies that I console-send using a POST method to a sign up page.
I manage via GET method (asking the sign up) to get the cookie information, but I see that in the POST method, the cookie is sent with a CID (Client ID) information to the server (CID comes from a Google Analytics function)

My question is : if I want to do a POST request to the server, the problem is that I don't have the Client ID, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

see this, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

I think you have to create your own clientId or &cid param, because the order hand you will need put script

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->

    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y','auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

in your index.jsp and take the cid of the cookie value of _ga....

A greeting.